# Dual sim phone - work / private how does it work?

Tags: dual-sim

I have a work and a private phone which can be a bit annoying at times carrying them both around. I like to keep them both separate so i can turn the work one off when on holiday etc to avoid the temptation of checking e-mails, returning missed calls etc.  If i had both these sims in a dual sim phone, if i go away on holiday or just want to turn the work one off for instance, can this be done so i don't receive calls / e-mails from the work one but maintain the private one without having to physically remove the sim.

A dual sim phone may be what i am after, but if i can't do this it will be a non starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can actually do that just go to settings then simcard management then switch the simcard you don't want off for turning it on back do the same process again